# Using redirect in serving files from a Git repo

Tags: git

I would like to set up a server to serve assets straight from a Git repo.  That way, I can create an index file that looks like

```
<script src="http://myserver.org/myrepo/481c400bd1/main.js"></script>
```

And main.js would arrange to download all files from the same place.

And then all that would be required to do a new "deploy" to production is update the commit-hash. It does not seem like a huge challenge, but I do have a question.

Of course, the vast majority of all files do not change from one deployment to the next, but since I want the commit-hash to be in the URL, every deployment completely invalidates the cache.

What would be better would be instead of serving the file directly, it would 301-redirect to the object-hash!  So "http://myserver.org/myrepo/481c400bd1/main.js" would be answered with 301 and "Location: http://myserver.org/myrepo/objects/56236c4e7cffe385".  Typically, under this system, my users would already have the file cached by its object-hash, if only they know what it is.

My questions

- Is this a good idea?
- Is there already a (NodeJS?  Java?) library to do this?
- How does this interact with mime-type?  Doesn't a server often guess the mime-type from the file name?

Comment: You don't minify your JS when  you deploy?  Or is this something low traffic enough that it doesn't matter?

Comment: @R0MANARMY -- I am experimenting with various ideas, including checking in minified code to a /dist directory, minifying on the fly, and not minifying.